# reference a method from a class by using a variable

Tags: java

I know how in Java, a class is referenced like `com.google.googlemaps.exampleClass.exampleMethod()`.
Is it possible to interchange the first parts of the referenece (in this case, the `com.google.googlemaps`) using a variable (`Class c`)?

**EDIT**
Ok, after some confusion, I'm going to (try to) provide an example

We have Class `A`. I can add a new instance of it. Each instance has the variables `name` (a String), and `redir` (currently in turmoil). `redir` is the variable which is supposed to hold the reference for the class, so I can call a specific method from those classes, so `redir` is like `com.google.googlemaps` etc.

Comment: I don't think Java supports C# aliases, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Could you not simply put `import com.google.googlemaps.*` at the top of your code?

Comment: I don't get it. Having `com.google.googlemaps.exampleClass.exampleMethod()` you want to change the first part and have, say, `net.anotherpackage.exampleClass.exampleMethod()`?

Comment: You say `a class is referenced` and the object referenced is a method...

Comment: acdcjunior has the right idea. That's what I want to do, but I'm having problems wording it =/

Answer (score 0):

Like `c.exampleMethod()`?

Yes, like so

```
import com.google.googlemaps.ExampleClass;
...
ExampleClass c = new ExampleClass();
c.exampleMethod();
```

Comment: it's not that simple. I need to easily, and without editing, be able to change one reference for another

Comment: Ray Stojonic - So I can interchange references without hard-coding them into the file.

Comment: @HX6 I want to give you an answer, but I just don't follow you. Can you update your question with some examples of what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

from your example:

```
com.google.googlemaps.exampleClass.exampleMethod()
```

the `exampleMethod()` is a static method.

If you have an object/reference with Type `Class<com.google.googlemaps.exampleClass>` (`Class c`) you can call [getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get the `Method` object. And then you could call [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method to invoke the method.

Comment: "Class<com.google.googlemaps.exampleClass> (Class c)"
I want to be able to change the things inside of the <>

Comment: you can `Class.forName(whatevername)` then you have the class reference. if the name is correct and the class exists. then getMethod and invoke.